# tombstone_failure_threshold is maintained per table or for whole cassanandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, tombstone

The `tombstone_failure_threshold` default value is 100000. But is this value for each table or for the whole cluster? I am confused. If one table exceeds this value, will range queries in other tables also be aborted? Please explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This parameter is set cluster-wide, but it's applied to *individual queries* - when query is running, and during data processing it finds that number of tombstones are greater than this parameter, then it will abort execution of this query...

It could be a situation, when you performed deletion of data, but most of deletion happened only in some partitions, so some queries on this table may work, and some could be aborted.

Comment: Thanks for your response . Is number of tombstones are counted for that particular tables only or it also include tombstone count  from  other table also ??

Comment: It's counted for particular query - when data is read, then it's read as-is, together with tombstones. During this read, they are counted, and if the value is greater than configured, query is aborted - this is why I wrote that query may work on the same table where another query isn't working